# Scrapy Python fill form and get data

Tags: python, forms, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to use Scrapy to download data automatically from a website.

What I have to do is the following:

- log-in into the website with my credentials
- select the data I want by writing a code on the 'RIC' line and selecting the period of interest
  [image]
- after I click 'Get data', the .csv file is generated and I can download it from the 'download/' url, where all my files are available like this: 
  [image]

I am able to log-in using 'FormRequest'. Therefore I thought about doing the same in order to fill the 'RIC' code and click the 'Get data' button but this fails. (I am not changing the dates now just to understand how it works fist)

Here my code:

```
class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "dmoz"
allowed_domains = ["myDomain"]
start_urls = [
    "http://myDomain/dataServices/"
]

def parse(self, response):
    return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formdata={'username': 'myName', 'password': 'myPass'},
        callback=self.after_login
    )

def after_login(self, response):
    # check login succeed before going on
    if "Your email adress and password did not match" in response.body:
        print("\n\nFAIL\n\n")
        self.logger.error("Login failed")
        return

    else:
        print("\n\n LOGIN SUCCESSFUL \n\n")

        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        ## THIS FAILS !!!
        return scrapy.http.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formxpath='//input[@value = ""]',
            formdata={'value': 'DJ@'},
            clickdata={'value': 'Get data'},
            callback= self.foo
        )
```

This is the html of the form:

```
<form method="post" action="."><div style='display:none'><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='6b16efca43f6d99b34e46561ebf6a1ab' /></div>
RIC (s) : <input name="ric" value=""  size="20" />(one or several rics separated by spaces)<br /><br />
Begin date : <script>DateInput('beginDate', true, 'YYYYMMDD','20110303')</script>
<!-- <input type="button" onClick="alert(this.form.orderdate.value)" value="Show date value passed"> -->

<!--<input name="beginDate" value=""  size="60" /> --><br />
End Date : <script>DateInput('endDate', true, 'YYYYMMDD','20110306') </script><br />
<input type="submit" value="Get data" /> </form>
```

The error that I get from the log:

```
2015-10-20 18:49:53 [scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <POST http://myDomain/dataServices/> (failed 1 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2015-10-20 18:49:53 [scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <POST http://myDomain/dataServices/> (failed 2 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2015-10-20 18:49:53 [scrapy] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <POST http://myDomain/dataServices/> (failed 3 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2015-10-20 18:49:53 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (500) <POST http://myDomain/dataServices/> (referer: http://myDomain/dataServices/)
2015-10-20 18:49:53 [scrapy] DEBUG: Ignoring response <500 http://myDomain/dataServices/>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
```

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The 'formxpath' kwarg should be an xpath that actually contains a form element as indicated in the [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.FormRequest) - "the first form that matches the xpath will be used". So, if theres only one form in the html page, no need to use 'formxpath'.

In this case while submitting the form you need to construct 'formdata' appropriately which should have values for ric, beginDate and endDate ( basically all form elements like input, select etc which does not have a default value in the html or whose values needs to be changed/overridden ) just like your code had for the login form submit.

```
    return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response( response,
        formdata={'ric': 'Some RIC Code', 'beginDate': '20110303', 'endDate': '20110306'},
        callback=self.after_ric_form_submit
    )

def after_ric_form_submit(self, response):
    #go to download page...
    yield Request('http://myDomain/download/', callback = self.download_csv)
```